# Move label with UISlider

Tags: iphone, ios, uislider

I have a requirement that i have to move value on label with UISlider. I tried with this code

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(dragMoving:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDragInside];

- (void)dragMoving:(UIControl *)c withEvent:ev {  
    UITouch *touch = [[ev allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
     sliderLabe.frame = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x,250, 270, 40);
}
```

sliderLabel is just below the slider, But it is giving me strange result when i drag faster but it works fine if i move mu slider slowly.

Comment: What kind of _strange result_ do you have in mind?

Comment: If i drag it very fast the slider goes to one side but label gets stuck in between somewhere.

Comment: This is probably because slider also calls `valueChanged` while you're moving it. Maybe you should place your label-moving-code there (if `slider.continuous` is set to YES). Though you wouldn't have a direct `touch` location available there. You'd have to calculate it from slider's `origin.x`, `width`, `minimumValue`, `maximumValue` and `value`. It's just an idea, not sure, if the performance would actually improve.

Comment: Good to hear. I'll add it as an answer, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While slider is moving it's also calculating it's new value and calling `valueChanged`. This could interfere with your extra `UIControlEventTouchDragInside` handler.

If `slider.continuous` is set to `YES` you could try moving youre label-moving-code into `valueChanged` handler.

Of course touch location is not known in this method so it needs to be calculated from slider's other properties: `frame.origin.x`, `frame.size.width`, `minimumValue`, `maximumValue` and `value`